# Printing boolean values True/False with the format() method in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, string-formatting, string.format

I was trying to print a truth table for Boolean expressions. While doing this, I stumbled upon the following:

```
>>> format(True, "") # shows True in a string representation, same as str(True)
'True'
>>> format(True, "^") # centers True in the middle of the output string
'1'
```

As soon as I specify a format specifier, `format()` converts `True` to `1`. I know that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so that `True` evaluates to `1`:

```
>>> format(True, "d") # shows True in a decimal format
'1'
```

But why does using the format specifier change `'True'` to `1` in the first example?

I turned to the [docs for clarification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). The only thing it says is:

> A general convention is that an empty format string (`""`) produces the same result as if you had called `str()` on the value. A non-empty format string typically modifies the result.

So the string gets modified when you use a format specifier. But why the change from `True` to `1` if *only* an alignment operator (e.g. `^`) is specified?

Comment: "A general convention is that an empty format string ("") produces the same result as if you had called str() on the value. A non-empty format string typically modifies the result." -- [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: I don't know why it's done like that, but if you want to fix it you could do `format(str(True),"^")`

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed it, but I was just curious as to the "why" :)

Comment: My guess is it has to do with an implicit conversion for the ``'^'`` operator, although that is weird. Also note that ``'^'`` is the *align-center* operator, not the width operator.

Comment: Yes, it _is_ weird. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excellent question! I believe I have the answer. This requires digging around through the Python source code in C, so bear with me.

First, `format(obj, format_spec)` is just syntactic sugar for `obj.__format__(format_spec)`. For specifically where this occurs, you'd have to look in [abstract.c](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/abstract.c#L721), in the function:

```c
PyObject *
PyObject_Format(PyObject* obj, PyObject *format_spec)
{
    PyObject *empty = NULL;
    PyObject *result = NULL;

    ...

    if (PyInstance_Check(obj)) {
        /* We're an instance of a classic class */
HERE -> PyObject *bound_method = PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "__format__");
        if (bound_method != NULL) {
            result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(bound_method,
                                                  format_spec,
                                                  NULL);

    ...
}
```

To find the exact call, we have to look in [intobject.c](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/intobject.c#L1113):

```c
static PyObject *
int__format__(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *format_spec;

    ...

    return _PyInt_FormatAdvanced(self,
                     ^           PyBytes_AS_STRING(format_spec),
                     |           PyBytes_GET_SIZE(format_spec));
               LET'S FIND THIS
    ...
}
```

`_PyInt_FormatAdvanced` is actually defined as a macro in [formatter_string.c](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Python/formatter_string.c#L11) as a function found in [formatter.h](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/stringlib/formatter.h#L879):

```c
static PyObject*
format_int_or_long(PyObject* obj,
               STRINGLIB_CHAR *format_spec,
           Py_ssize_t format_spec_len,
           IntOrLongToString tostring)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    PyObject *tmp = NULL;
    InternalFormatSpec format;

    /* check for the special case of zero length format spec, make
       it equivalent to str(obj) */
    if (format_spec_len == 0) {
        result = STRINGLIB_TOSTR(obj);   <- EXPLICIT CAST ALERT!
        goto done;
    }

    ... // Otherwise, format the object as if it were an integer
}
```

And therein lies your answer. A simple check for whether `format_spec_len` is `0`, and if it is, convert `obj` into a string. As you well know, `str(True)` is `'True'`, and the mystery is over!

Comment: I think the OP is asking why ``'^'.format(True) == '1'``, not why ``''.format(True) == 'True'``. Or rather why there would be an implicit cast to ``int`` for the former when the latter properly evaluates.

Comment: `True` *is* an `int`, and it's only cast out of an `int` and into a `str` when `format_spec` is empty.

Comment: Not in python it isn't. ``>>> type(True) = <type 'bool'>``, and ``type(True) == type(1) == False``. In the underlying C code in the C interpreter it obviously is converted into an ``int`` since C lacks a bool primitive, but that wouldn't explain the implicit conversion on the python side.

Comment: The conversion happens on the C side, not the python side. All of the `format` business I reference above happens entirely in C.

Comment: Again, that wouldn't explain the implicit conversion. ``>>> 'The Bool is {}'.format(True) == 'The Bool is True'``. It seems to only do it when you specify arguments into the ``{}``, I.E. ``'The Bool is {:^}'.format(True) == 'The Bool is 1'``, however ``'The Bool is {!r:^}'.format(True) == 'The Bool is True'``

Comment: I don't think we disagree here. I haven't looked at it closely, but `str.format(*args, **kwargs)` (which I believe is implemented on the C side [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/string_format.h)) seems like a helper for `obj.__format__(format_spec)`. So `'{!cast:format_spec}'.format(True)` --> `(cast(obj)).__format__(format_spec)` appears completely consistent with each other.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/string_format.h#L478) we go. When rendering the objects passed into `str.format(*args, **kwargs)`, a call to `obj.__format__(format_spec)` is made. There's some handling for doing a cast [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/string_format.h#L769), before the `__format__` call is made.

Comment: @HuuNguyen Thanks for looking into this. I've tried reading the C source code, but my C isn't too good. I do see that using an empty format specifier makes `format(obj, "") == str(obj)`. But I can't really find anything that would explain why `format(True) == 'True' != format(True, "^")`. I would very much appreciate if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: If you're wondering why `format(True, "^")` is `1` and not `'True'`, then you already know. It's because internally, `True` is represented as an integer. The only time it ever is *not* an integer is when you cast it explicitly using `'{!r:}'.format(True)`, or you specify an empty `format_spec`. Even though `'^'` is *just* an alignment operator, it is *still non-empty*, so the code path for the explicit conversion above is bypassed. In every case that is not these two exceptions, `True` is just a `1`, and is formatted as an integer.

Comment: So it would be correct to say that the printed `'True'` is the exception, not the printed `'1'`? It really is a corner case, by the way, because I can't think of any other type that would behave like members of class `bool` in combination with `format()`.

Comment: Correct, it is very much the exception. For all other objects without an explicit C-side `__format__` implementation, the object is converted into a string and then `__format__` is called on that string. You can see that happening [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/abstract.c#L781-L796). For funsies, try `format(True, "c")` and you'll truly see that `bool` is an `int` to the bone! Except, of course, in the two cases I pointed out.

Comment: To clarify: Since `bool` is a subclass of `int` but `bool` doesn't specify it's own `__format__` method the one from `int` is used through regular inheritance. In the case of the special handling of an empty format string, `str()` is called on the object which *is* implemented for `bool`.

Comment: So, in order to have both non-empty format string (such as for alignment) and boolean printed as true/false, we should first str(boolean) and send this (as a string) to format function?

Comment: @dragonxlwang exactly! Keep in mind the formatting rules will treat it as if it were a string for the entire duration of the function call, from beginning to end.